# Implementing NSCopying in Subclass of Subclass

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, hierarchy, nscopying

I have a small class hierarchy that I'm having trouble implementing `copyWithZone:` for. I've read the NSCopying documentation, and I can't find the correct answer.

Take two classes: **Shape** and **Square**. Square is defined as:

```
@interface Square : Shape
```

No surprise there. Each class has **one** property, Shape has a "sides" int, and Square has a "width" int. The `copyWithZone:` methods are seen below:

**Shape**

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    Shape *s = [[Shape alloc] init];
    s.sides = self.sides;
    return s;
}
```

**Square**

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    Square *s = (Square *)[super copyWithZone:zone];
    s.width = self.width;
    return s;
}
```

Looking at the documentation, this seems to be the "right" way to do things.

**It is not.**

If you were to try to set/access the width property of a Square returned by the `copyWithZone:` method, **it would fail** with an error similar to the one below:

```
2010-12-17 11:55:35.441 Hierarchy[22617:a0f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Shape setWidth:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10010c970'
```

Calling `[super copyWithZone:zone];` in the Square method actually returns a Shape. It's a miracle you're even allowed to set the width property in that method.

That having been said, *how does one implement NSCopying* for subclasses in a way that *does not make them responsible* for copying the variables of its superclass?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

One of those things you realize right after asking...

The implementation of `copyWithZone:` in the superclass (**Shape**) shouldn't be assuming it's a Shape. So instead of the *wrong* way, as I mentioned above:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    Shape *s = [[Shape allocWithZone:zone] init];
    s.sides = self.sides;
    return s;
}
```

You should instead use:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    Shape *s = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init]; // <-- NOTE CHANGE
    s.sides = self.sides;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `allocWithZone:` instead of `alloc` ?

Comment: As an aside - while the idea of memory zones is an interesting one, it never really proved feasible. While `allocWithZone:` might be the common signature, `alloc` will do you just fine these days.