# Problems while making an array and assign elements to a UITableViewCell and get it labelText element back

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift

As title say i have this code:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var placesTableCells:[UITableViewCell] = []
var temporalCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
for i in 0...10 {
    temporalCell?.textLabel?.text = "ola k ace \(i)"
    placesTableCells.append(temporalCell!)
    println(placesTableCells[i].textLabel!.text!)
}
println()
for i in 0...10 {
    println(placesTableCells[i].textLabel!.text!)
}
```

All works fine when i request placesTableCells within the for loop, it prints:

```
ola k ace 0
ola k ace 1
ola k ace 2
ola k ace 3
ola k ace 4
ola k ace 5
ola k ace 6
ola k ace 7
ola k ace 8
ola k ace 9
ola k ace 10
```

But when i request the array out of it it just return "ola k ace 10" ten times, it prints:

```
ola k ace 10
ola k ace 10
ola k ace 10
ola k ace 10
ola k ace 10
ola k ace 10
ola k ace 10
ola k ace 10
ola k ace 10
ola k ace 10
ola k ace 10
```

Where is the problem there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason for that is that you have declared temporalCell outside your for loop and you keep changing it's value everytime in the loop which also changes the value of the previous reference objects in the array.

If you wish to add distinct objects in the array, move your temporalCell declaration in the for loop as such

```
var placesTableCells:[UITableViewCell] = []
for i in 0...10 {
    var temporalCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    temporalCell.textLabel?.text = "ola k ace \(i)"
    placesTableCells.append(temporalCell)
    println(placesTableCells[i].textLabel!.text!)
}
println()
for i in 0...10 {
    println(placesTableCells[i].textLabel!.text!)
}
```

And it should work.
Let me know.

Comment: yes it worked very fine, but i can't understand it at all, since im doing append it should add a new object to the array and not mess with the another objects?

Comment: Thanks for accepting as answer! The basic problem is that even though you are appending the object everytime, you are appending the same object after changing the value which means that even the objects at the previous index in the array which are basically references to your master object have their values changed. Read up on "Classes are reference types" here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_145 and value types vs reference types in OOLs in general :)

Comment: ohh i got it, then basically what i did was make an object and then refer it in all 11 array elements, is there a way to tell the compiler to copy the class object instead of reference it?

Comment: Check out copyWithZone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072729/how-can-i-make-a-deep-copy-in-objective-c