# Correct way to implement NSCopying for class hiearchy

Tags: objective-c

What's the best practice for implementing NSCopying across a two class inheritance hierarchy? I would like to have a deep copy of both Square and Shape's properties on a copy.

The 3 questions I have:

1. Do both the parent and child class need to declare that they're implementing `NSCopying` or it adequate to only declare it on the base class?
2. I've seen some people use `[instance copy]` instead of `[instance copyWithZone:]` Is this just a preference or is it more correct to use: `copyWithZone`?
3. When copying arrays, is it correct to do: `newObj.list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.list copyItems:YES];`

Here's what I have:

```
@interface Shape : NSObject <NSCopying>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *sides;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *list;
@end

@implementation Shape 

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    Shape *shape = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];

    // Is it correct to use copyWithZone: instead of copy? eg: [self.name copy]
    shape->_name = [self.name copyWithZone:zone];
    shape->_sides = [self.sides copyWithZone:zone];
    shape->_list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.list copyItems:YES];

    return shape;
}
@end

// Does this class also need to declare <NSCopying>?
@interface Square : Shape 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *color;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *corners;
@end

@implementation Square
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    // Will this ensure a deep copy of the inherited properties?
    Square *square = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];

    square->_color = [self.color copyWithZone:zone];    
    square->_corners = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.corners copyItems:YES];

    return square;
}
@end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing NSCopying in Subclass of Subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472904/implementing-nscopying-in-subclass-of-subclass)

Comment: Sort of. I did see that question but it didn't answer all of the questions I had.

Comment: Please be more specific about your questions, then. What exactly don't you understand? What exactly isn't answered there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do both the parent and child class need to declare that they're implementing NSCopying or it adequate to only declare it on the base class?

It is a matter of style. I generally do not declare `NSCopying` again, but it may provide a little clarity if it's not obvious.

> I've seen some people use [instance copy] instead of [instance copyWithZone:] Is this just a preference or is it more correct to use: copyWithZone?

It is fine to call `copy`. Zones haven't been used in a very long time (I don't believe that OS X ever used them.) You should override `copyWithZone:`, however.

> When copying arrays, is it correct to do: newObj.list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.list copyItems:YES];

Yes, this is necessary, but is not sufficient if the objects in the array do not implement a deep copy in their `copyWithZone:`. Note that this calls `copy`, not `mutableCopy`. So if you have an array of mutable arrays, you will wind up with an array of arrays. If you need to maintain mutability, you have to call `mutableCopy` yourself.

You have made one mistake, however:

```
// Will this ensure a deep copy of the inherited properties?
Square *square = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
```

No, you need to call:

```
Square *square = [super copy];
```

Comment: If a copy is done as mentioned, should a subsequent isEqual check on the existing and cloned objects return true? Would I need to implement a custom isEqual?

Comment: You would need to implement a custom `-isEqual:` and a custom `-hash`. The default `-isEqual` validates that the objects are actually the same object. You must always implement `-hash` if you implement `-isEqual:`.